# Mouse Event Handling for an Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent

I made a *Search Box*, roughly coding is like this

```
<table id="searchBox" style="border:1px solid #555;">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="text" style="border:none" id="myTextBox" onclick="makeActive();" />
  </td>
  <td>
   <select onclick="makeActive();">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
   </select>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**Functions**

```
function makeActive() {
 document.getElementById("searchBox").style.border="1px solid #ff0000";
}
function makeUnactive() {
 document.getElementById("searchBox").style.border="1px solid #555";
}
```

**My Requirement :**
As the code says that when user either click `textbox` or `selectbox` the table border changes which shows that the `searchbox is Active` now, and **i want that when user click outside the searchbox table `function makeUnactive()` should be called**, i tried to use `onblur="makeUnactive();"` within `textbox` so the script is also called when i click `selectbox` or `Submit Button` which is wrong :(

---

## Edited

its working fine now `check my answer below How I Did It`

---

Comment: On your website (profile), **you are selling illegal goods** ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onfocus` property call active function.To make a field inactive, call inactive function in `onblur` property.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zsfqd/)**

Working fine:

**HTML**

```
<table id="searchBox" style="border:1px solid #555;">
 <tr>
<td>
<input type="text" style="border:none" onclick="makeActive()" onblur="makeUnactive()"/>
</td>
<td>
<select onclick="makeActive();" onblur="makeUnactive()">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
function makeActive() {
document.getElementById("searchBox").style.border="1px solid red";}
function makeUnactive() {
document.getElementById("searchBox").style.border="1px solid yellow";
}
```

Comment: hmm but using this too the problem is same :(

Comment: @AbarChoudhary where have you put your functions?

Comment: oh actually i didnt used Selectbox in real , i made my own Selectbox using div's and i made an arrow image clicking on which my selectbox is visible

Comment: here is the full working of my searchbox [link](http://abarchoudhary.allalla.com/searchbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Try just using CSS

```
#id:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**oh i got the answer :D**

it can be achieved if `i don't get Lost Focus from the Text Box` so i created a new `function` which runs when either `Select Box or Submit Button is clicked` so now i can use `onblur` to my `Text Box` :D

```
function makeFocus() {
 myTextBox.focus();
}
```

Thanx all of you **:***